# Java application saves image on project folder instead of eclipse folder

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat

I'm trying to save an image file to my project folder. 
Image file comes from database. 
It is a maven project and rest web service. 
I don't have any servlets. 
Here is my code, but it saves on eclipse folder.

```
        byte[] imgData = null;
        Blob img = null;
        img = resultset.getBlob("LOGO");
        imgData = img.getBytes(1, (int) img.length());

        BufferedImage img2 = null;
        img2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData));

        File outputfile = new File("birimler/"+resultset.getString("BASLIK")
                + "Logo.png");
        outputfile.mkdirs();
        ImageIO.write(img2, "png", outputfile);
        System.out.println(outputfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Output is: `/Users/xxx/Documents/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/birimler/imageLogo.png`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because eclipse working dir is his installation folder.
Provide a full absolute path, or change the working dir of your run configuration.

```
File outputfile = new File("/birimler/"+resultset.getString("BASLIK")
                + "Logo.png");
```

Would end up in

> "/birimler/imageLogo.png"

And adding one more slash:

```
File outputfile = new File("/birimler/"+resultset.getString("BASLIK")
                + "/Logo.png");
```

would produce:

> "/birimler/image/Logo.png"

Comment: It's on my local machine now, later i'm gonna use in tomcat8 on server. if i change dir from eclipse, it is not working on server.

Comment: Later on server, the working dir auf the tomcat is normaly his installation folder. Anyway, provide absolute path to be sure of the destination.

Comment: Thanks for helping but how can i provide an absolute path. Local machine's os is Mac OSX and the server's is Windows.

Comment: By adding a slash in front of your path! Or if you want to make it write use File.separator , with is eitehr / or \ depending on OS

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and check my answer as correct, when it helped